# Angular Nested Comments - Values undefined when submitting form

Tags: comments, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-forms, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to get a dynamic script for nested comments to work.

My first problem is that I don't know how I can do endless nesting. For now I planned to do 3 layers, cause I don't know how to make it work dynamicly.

The second problem is that when i submit the form, the values of the models is not submitted to the JS-script. The values are just undefined.

I guess my approach is just wrong - The ng-model elements are not bound inside of the ng-repeat, also the values of all forms would be bound to the same element... Maybe someone has some tips. If it is important, my backend runs with Laravel 4. Here is my code

```js
var commentsApp = angular.module('commentsApp', []);

function CommentsCtrl($scope, $http, $compile) {

    var url_segments = window.location.host.split('.');
    var section = url_segments[0];

    $http.get('/api/' + section + window.location.pathname + '/comments').success(function (comments) {
        $scope.comments = comments;
    });

    $scope.toggleForm = function (id) {

        var container = document.getElementById(id);

        var html = '<br/><input name="category" type="text" ng-model="person.category" placeholder="Category" required/><span class="alert alert-error ng-show="add-bro.input.$error.required">Required</span>';

        var elem = $compile(html)($scope);
        angular.element(container).append(elem);
    }

    $scope.addComment = function () {
        var comment = {
            body: $scope.body,
            commentable_id: $scope.commentable_id,
            commentable_type: $scope.commentable_type
        };

        $scope.comments.push(comment);
    };


}

commentsApp.controller('CommentsCtrl', CommentsCtrl);
```

```html
 <div class="content-row basic" ng-controller="CommentsCtrl" class="comments">
                    <form ng-submit="addComment()">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="body">
                        <input type="hidden" value="@{{c.id}}" ng-model="commentable_id">
                        <input type="hidden" value="Player" ng-model="commentable_type">
                        <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                    </form>

                    <div ng-repeat="c in comments" class="comment">
                        <span>@{{c.author.username}}</span>
                        <p>@{{c.body}}</p>
                        <a href class="reply-link" ng-click="showForm = !showForm">Answer</a>
                        <div class="reply-container" ng-show="showForm">
                            <form ng-submit="addComment()">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="body">
                                <input type="hidden" value="@{{c.id}}" ng-model="commentable_id">
                                <input type="hidden" value="Comment" ng-model="commentable_type">
                                <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div ng-repeat="cc in c.comments" class="s-comment">
                            <span>@{{cc.author.username}}</span>
                            <p>@{{cc.body}}</p>
                            <a href class="reply-link" ng-click="showForm = !showForm">Answer</a>
                            <div class="reply-container" ng-show="showForm">
                                <form ng-submit="addComment()">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="body">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="@{{c.id}}" ng-model="commentable_id">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="Comment" ng-model="commentable_type">
                                    <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div ng-repeat="ccc in cc.comments" class="ss-comment">
                                <span>@{{ccc.author.username}}</span>
                                <p>@{{ccc.body}}</p>
                                <a href class="reply-link" ng-click="showForm = !showForm">Answer</a>
                                <div class="reply-container" ng-show="showForm">
                                    <form ng-submit="addComment()">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="body">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="@{{c.id}}" ng-model="commentable_id">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="Comment" ng-model="commentable_type">
                                        <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            //Comments object having reply oject
            $scope.comments = [{ comment: 'hi', reply: [{ comment: 'hi inside commnet' }, { comment: 'hi inside commnet' }] }];

            //push reply
            $scope.insertReply = function (index, reply) {
                $scope.comments[index].reply.push({ comment: reply });
            }

            //push commnet
            $scope.newComment = function (comment) {
                $scope.comments.push({ comment:comment, reply: [] });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <!--Comment section-->
        <ul ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index" style="background: skyblue; padding: 10px;">
            <li>
                <b>Comment {{$index}} : </b>
                <br>
                {{comment.comment}}
                <!--Reply section-->
                    <ul ng-repeat="reply in comment.reply track by $index">
                        <li><i>Reply {{$index}} :</i><br>
                            {{reply.comment}}</li>
                    </ul>
                <!--End reply section-->
                <input type="text" ng-model="reply" placeholder=" Write your reply." /><a href="" ng-click="insertReply($index,reply)">Reply</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--End comment section -->
            

        <!--Post your comment-->
        <b>New comment</b>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your comment" ng-model="comment" />
        <a href="" ng-click="newComment(comment)">Post </a>
    </div>
```